# Calling method 2 classes down from current method C#

Tags: c#, class, encryption

So I have a main class that has a list of objects.

```
List<Media> media = new List<Media>();
```

The media class is an abstract class. There is a class called Book that inherits from media.  Following is an example of adding a book to the media list.

```
media.Add(new Book(mediaInfo[1], Convert.ToInt32(mediaInfo[2]), mediaInfo[3], summary));
```

mediaInfo is an array of values that gets passed into the constructor.

```
string[] mediaInfo = record.Split('|');
```

When the summary is passed into media it is encrypted.  The book class contains a Decrypt() method that will decrypt it and that works fine.  The problem is when I try to call it I get an error saying Decrypt is not in Media. So how do I call it.
I tried this but I get the error.

```
foreach (Media m in media)
{
   if (m.Search(query))
   {

      if (m.GetType() == typeof(Book))
      {
          Console.WriteLine(m.ToString() + m.Decrypt());
      }
   }
}
```

I check if it is a Book so why can't it go down to Book to see if Decrypt is there.  I cannot put decrypt into the Media class because there is also a song class that is not encypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `m` is of type `Media` (which doesn't contain `Decrypt()`), you'll need to cast `m` to `Book`:

```
Console.WriteLine(m.ToString() + ((Book)m).Decrypt());
```

Comment: Thanks.  You are a legend.  Will mark as solution in 10 minutes when I can.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: This is another variant: `if (m is Book b) Console.WriteLine(m.ToString() + b.Decrypt());`

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching)

```
foreach (Media m in media)
{
   if (m.Search(query))
   {

      if (m is Book b)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(b.ToString() + b.Decrypt());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is actually a better answer than the accepted one, as this does not assume that all Media objects are actually Book objects. Although the OP doesn't specify, it's perfectly reasonable to add objects of other types, as long as they inherit from Media. This answer avoids the exception that would result if that happened.

Comment: To accepted answer's defence it plugs in into OP's code that checks the type first.